# Trouble reading and loading data from a CSV file in C++

Tags: c++, file-io, csv, fstream

I am creating a neural network in which I need to read data from a CSV file and store each line as a separate training set for the network inputs. Each line consists of a set of patterns and ends with the target output.

I have been able to read and parse the first line into its respective pointer lists and then store them in a vector by creating a new object of the base class that accepts two pointers.

The problem is that I can not figure out how to read a line from the file, store that set in object pointer vector, and then keep reading each line until the end of the file, while storing each line that the vector. I would greatly appreciate any help that could be provided along with possible suggestions that may be more efficient  or optimal.

```
void processLine( string &line )
{

      double* pattern = new double[numPatterns];
      double* target = new double[numTargets];


      char* cstr = new char[line.size()+1];
      char* t;
      strcpy(cstr, line.c_str());

      int i = 0;
      t=strtok (cstr,",");

      while ( t!=NULL && i < (numPatterns + numTargets) )
      { 
        if ( i < numPatterns ) pattern[i] = atof(t);
        else target[i - numPatterns] = atof(t);

        //move token onwards
        t = strtok(NULL,",");
        i++;            
     }


     data.push_back( new priceEntries( pattern, target ) );     
}


bool loadDataFile(const char* file, int numP, numT)
{
        numPatterns = numP;
    numTargets = numT;

    fstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open(filename, ios::in);  


    if ( inputFile.is_open() )
    {

         string line = "";

         //read data
         while ( getline(inputFile, line) )
         {      
          processLine(line);
         }

   random_shuffle(data.begin(), data.end());

   inputFile.close()

   return true;
   }

   else
   {
        cout << "File could not be opened.\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you have in order to get help.

Comment: Please check your code. You're at least missing a single brace. And please fix the indentation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be basic csv parsing. If so, I'd suggest using a simple parser library(libcsv comes to mind) instead of trying to handle the parsing from scratch.